# Edit Custom Scroll-Bars With JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrollbar

Is it possible to edit custom scroll-bars with javascript?

This is my custom scroll-bar:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 6px 1px grey; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: yellow; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 6px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: #000000;
}
```

Changing the scrollbar like so (does not work):

```
jQuery('::-webkit-scrollbar').css('width', '120px');
jQuery('::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb').css('background', 'orange');
```

or

```
document.body.scrollbar.style.width = '120px';
document.body.scrollbar.thumb.style.background = 'orange';
```

How does one go about doing this? Thank you.

Comment: What I'm trying to do with this is make a custom scrollbar which reacts to when the mouse hovers over it. When the mouse hovers over the scrollbar, the width increases so it is easier for the user to drag the scrollbar thumb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of research, I found that it is impossible to edit the browser's default scrollbar with javascript.

The only solution that I found viable was to use jScrollPane and jQuery's `.hover()` capabilities to edit the custom html-scrollbar.

You can also apply CSS to the custom html-scrollbar, making it like the browser's defalt scrollbar + javascript editing.

An example of this can be found [here](http://usandfriends.x10.mx/iScroll).